# Symfony in legacy application: Why do i get "You are not authenticated"?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I'm trying to integrate a legacy application in symfony fullstack.
Because of poor infrastructure I have to stick to symfony 2.8.

Everything works so far, but i think i maybe have a problem with sessions.
(I read the symfony articles about integrating legacy sessions and tried everything)

The Toolbar says "You are not authenticated".
Normally there is "Authenticated anonymously".

[image: You are not authenticated.]

[image: unhovered]

This is how it should look.
(Screen from a plain install of symfony2.8 in the exact same version i use)[image]

**What are possible reasons for that?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Those sound like the same thing to me. Are you sure the message didn't just change slightly?

Comment: Yes, I'm quite sure.
If i do not hover the section it is in "warn because everything will explode"-RED
(screenshot added in question)

Comment: It's probably red to indicate you're not logged in. What do you envision the difference between "anonymous authentication" and "not being logged in" actually are? If you log in, do things work correctly? Is *anything* actually *not working* due to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the legacy application failed and directly rendered a response from within an event listener. I can't really explain it, but now it works.